# Input array using numpy getting valueError setting array element with sequence and inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimension

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

**THIS IS THE ERROR I RECIEVE IN JUPYTER NOTEBOOK!**
**Why am I getting this error I have arrays with 7 columns per row**

```
  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-22-8bce85373ca3> in <module>
          1 # Input (temp, rainfall, humidity, airspeed, solar, electricity, cost)
    ----> 2 inputs = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.5],
          3                    [8, 9, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6.5],
          4                    [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13.5],
          5                    [1, 14, 2, 15, 3, 16, 4.5],
    
    ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (684,) + inhomogeneous part
```

Comment: Do you see that part in your code?  Clearly there is more to that input (beyond line 5).  In some way or other the nest list input to `np.array` is not "rectantangular", that is, the sublists are not all the same length.  Youw need to examine that `inputs` line carefully.

Comment: Echoing what @hpaulj said; a useful approach here would be to isolate the issue as much as possible by making the smallest possible example that can be separated out from your code and run independently that causes the error. If you could post that, it would be easier to answer!

Comment: Your question as written does not include the part of the code that is actually causing the error.

Comment: Yes you were right. I was missing a comma, it was like 1500 lines and i swear i looked a dozen times. As Paul suggested one of my arrays only had 6 columns and not 7. Thanks Paul.